# Searching on the basis of a value in json

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have an attribute in my coredata model called `name` on the basis of which I'm able to search like so...

```
        filtered = self.newProdDetails.filter({( data : NewProduct) -> Bool in
            return (data.name!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
        })
```

Now I can load the `filtered` array in the `cellForRowAt..` when I want to search on the basis of name.

But for another view, there is another entity which has an attribute called `customerJson`. And this json has within it `customerName`on the basis of which I want to make a search.

In the scenario which I mentioned first, the element on the basis of which I wanted to search (`name`) was directly an attribute. But in the second case the element on the basis of which I want to search is within a json. So in this scenario, how can I assign values to the `filtered` array...?

I have done something like this...

```
        for element in orderDetails {

            if let jsonStr = element.value(forKey: "customerJson") as? String {

                let data = jsonStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {

                    for item in json {
                        if item.key == "first_name" {
                            var customerName = (item.value as? String)! //HERE I GET THE CUSTOMER NAME. BUT HOW CAN I ASSIGN IT TO 'filtered' ARRAY FOR THE PURPOSE OF SEARCHING, I CAN'T FIGURE OUT. 
                        }
                    }

                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply this had to be done within `if item.key == "first_name"` and it worked...

```
filterArr = self.orderDetails.filter({( data : Order) -> Bool in
      return (data.customerJson!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
 })
```